# Compiling Autopsy on Windows using netbeans command line

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, auto-update

when i compiling Autopsy4 on Windows10. Using command line ant.

when i play 'ant' command on root directory of autopsy, build.xml run.

build.xml called build-impl.xml, and this called platform.xml.

platform.xml run this:

```
<autoupdate installdir="${nbplatform.active.dir}" updatecenter="${autoupdate.catalog.url}">
```

${autoupdate.catalog.url} : http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

and fail build.

Error msg is:
INFO: The file at http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz, corresponding to the catalog at http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz, does not look like the gzip file, trying to parse it as the pure xml

this problem same on NetBeans IDE 8.2 GUI.

how to compile Auotpsy4 on windows10?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs in the linux version. I can download the catalog.xml.gz file using the browser but when I change the url to point to the file copy, that works but it then starts looking for other files with a similar URL and breaks.

I *think* the problem is the server has given the wrong MIMEType for the catalog.xml.gz file - which confuses ant.

I have no solution just yet, but I am exploring downloading the full web tree to local local directory tree

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for Linux that worked for me

edit platform.properties in autopsy/nbproject/

and switch http to **https**, final line looks like this:

autoupdate.catalog.url=https://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/${netbeans-plat-version}/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz